# Defining a function for velocity in terms of external variables?

Tags: functions, programming

I want to make a machine move a distance, *d*, in a time period of, *t*. But its acceleration, *a*, and therefore its velocity, *v*, must change depending on an external variable, *N*.

I want the machine to slow down as *N* increases and to speed up as *N* decreases. This must imply that $a \propto - \Delta N$ and $v \propto 1/N$

**Is it possible to create a function demonstrating how the velocity changes in this pre-set time period, *t* ?** How would *v* be defined?

*I am intending to write this for some code, but I would like to make the maths clearer for myself first.*

Answer (score 1):

The question as posed is unanswerable because it is both vague and self-contradictory. That would be the topic of a comment, but it's difficult to explain in the format of a comment just how vague and self-contradictory the question is, so here is an extended comment in a space that normally would be occupied by an answer.

The statement that $v \propto 1/N$ is a very specific statement about a particular relationship between $v$ and $N$, much more specific than the statement that $v$ increases as $N$ decreases and vice versa.

Literally, $v \propto 1/N$ says there is some constant $k$ such that

$$ v = \frac kN. $$

That implies that

$$
 a = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} v = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \frac kN
  = -\frac1{N^2} \frac{\mathrm dN}{\mathrm dt},
$$

which doesn't look like $a \propto - \Delta N$ under any reasonable interpretation I can think of.

You might want to reconsider what you mean here:

> I want the machine to slow down as *N* increases and to speed up as *N* decreases. This must imply that $a \propto - \Delta N$ and $v \propto 1/N$

There's no "must" about it; the first sentence does not imply either of the second two formulas **at all** (you could have something quite different) and the two formulas are mutually contradictory.

If you literally want the first sentence to be true, then $v$ is a function of $N$,
but it could be any decreasing function; if there is some reason that the choice of functions should be more limited than that, you'll have to articulate an idea of what that reason would be.

Alternatively, instead of defining $v$ directly as a function of $N,$ you could first define $a$ mathematically.
Slowing down as $N$ increases means $a$ is negative when $N$ is increasing;
speeding up as $N$ decreases means $a$ is positive when $N$ is decreasing.
That is, the sign of $a$ is opposite to the sign of $\frac{\mathrm dN}{\mathrm dt}.$
There are a lot of ways to define $a$ as a function of
$\frac{\mathrm dN}{\mathrm dt}$ that satisfy this requirement, for example,
$$
a = \begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if $\frac{\mathrm dN}{\mathrm dt} > 0$}, \\
\phantom{-}0 & \text{if $\frac{\mathrm dN}{\mathrm dt} = 0$}, \\
\phantom{-}1 & \text{if $\frac{\mathrm dN}{\mathrm dt} < 0$}, \\
\end{cases}
$$
but that's only one of a great many possible choices.
Note that with this particular choice, there are a lot of different ways to vary $N$ over a period of time $t = 0$ to $t = T$ and still come up with the same value of $v$ at time $T,$ and you can't determine $v$ at time $T$ just by looking at $N$ at time $T.$

On top of all this, if the machine must travel a particular distance in a particular interval of time, that's a constraint on $v$ that will be very hard to meet,
especially if $v$ is subject to the influence of some "external" variable $N$ that could vary unpredictably.
You need to seriously think about what you mean by
"move a distance, $d$, in a time period of, $t$"
and what you mean by
"depending on an external variable, $N$."
Why do you need both of these things?
These two things do not seem compatible within the framework of your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I can see how my question is flawed.
I want to use this programme to make a machine move a permanent distance, taking the same time to cover that distance. 
The machine will analyse a sample as it moves.  I want it to slow down at the points where $N$ is high and to pace up at points where N is low.  
This implies that at higher N, v is lower, and vice-versa. 
I thought that the acceleration between points a and b must also be slower if the change in N from point a to b is negative.
I was looking for an equation that would relate v or a to N and to t.

Comment: The comment above gives new information that is helpful. If the values of $N$ occur at fixed places along the path, we can consider the inverse of speed, time per unit distance traveled, which should be some kind of increasing function of $N$. Making this a continuous function might be a little more difficult. Also, it's going to be hard to determine the right speed in the early part of the path if you have no idea what values of $N$ you're going to encounter later. Do you know the $N$ values in advance? Values sampled at uniform distances with a known sum might work.

Comment: Thanks once again for the help. Indeed I have pre-determined the values $N$ at each time point. The data results in a slightly-deformed Gaussian-like distribution data set.
I still don't quite see how I can relate the quantities though......